# Reduce line-spacing in ToC for certain sections in amsbook

Tags: table-of-contents, line-spacing, amsbook

Is it possible in LaTeX to reduce the line-spacing in the table of contents just for certain sections? Left is how it currently looks like, right is how I want it to look like:

[image: Current] [image: Wanted]

Thanks a lot! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that the following command solves it for all chapters:

```
\def\l@chapter{\@tocline{0}{2pt plus1pt}{0pt}{}{}}}%
```

Default would be:

```
 \def\l@chapter{\@tocline{0}{8pt plus1pt}{0pt}{}{}}%
```

I solved the problem defining a new command:

```
\newcommand{\reducelinespaceintoc}{
    \addtocontents{toc}{%
        \protect\renewcommand*{\protect\l@chapter}{\protect\@tocline{0}{2pt plus1pt}{0pt}{}{}}
    }%
}
```

Before the chapter you want to reduce the spacing you can now put \reducelinespaceintoc. If you want to revert to normal spacing, just add another command using "8pt plus1pt" instead of "2pt plus1pt".

Comment: I changed my answer, so it provides a answer.